# Word for "pertaining to the interface"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I wish to say that my graphic design for a certain system (computer program) shall be adjusted to account for inherent limitations of the system's operation interface can I say "the design shall be adjusted to account for the program's *interfacial* limitations"? I.e. is there a word for "pertaining to the interface"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you could, interfacial is a word, and it can be used in the context you have described:

## [interfacial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interfacial?s=t)

> 2. of, relating to, or of the nature of an interface. - dictionary.com

However it would be far more natural to simply say:

> "The design shall be adjusted to account for the program's interface
> limitations"

or, slightly better:

> "The design shall be adjusted to account for the interface limitations of the program."

However, your example sentence aside, I think what you mean to say is:

> "The design shall be adjusted to account for the interface limitations of the system."

Because it is the system that has the interface, and not the program.

Comment: As a computer programmer, I can say that a "system" that includes a user interface is commonly a single computer program, and the words "program" and "system" can be used interchangeably in this instance, so I wouldn't correct the OP on their choice of words there.